# How to maintain a duplicate id of duplicate row of string in excel

Tags: excel

composition

```
Abacavir300  mg
Abacavir300  mg
Abacavir300  mg
Abacavir300  mg
Abacavir500  mg + 10  mg
Abacavir600  mg;Lamivudine300  mg
Abacavir600  mg;Lamivudine300  mg
Abatacept250  mg
Abciximab10  mg
Abciximab10  mg
Abciximab10  mg
Abciximab10  mg
Abciximab2  mg
Abiraterone Acetate250  mg
Abiraterone Acetate250  mg
Abiraterone Acetate250  mg
Abiraterone Acetate250  mg
Abiraterone Acetate250  mg
```

Above is my data of one column. in second column id should be written as 
Composition Id

```
1
1
1
1
2
3
3
4
5 
5
5
5
6
6
6
6
6
```

I used COUNTIF(range,criteria) but it shows the number of occurrences of duplicate data.

[Image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/04Ksd.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This formula would do what you request, type in to `cell B2` the following formula.

`=IF(COUNTIF(A$2:A2,A2)=1,MAX(B$1:B1)+1,VLOOKUP(A2,A$1:B1,2,0))` 
[image]

Answer (score 0):

In `Cell B2` write `1` then in `Cell B3` enter the following formula

```
=IF(A3=A2,B2,B2+1)
```

Drag/Copy down as required. See image for reference.

[image]